# WEB9102: Web Login Failed

Tags: java, java-ee

Mi problema consiste en que estoy intentando crear un login en JSF 2.2 con Java EE 7, Glassfish 4.1.2, base de datos PostgreSQL y ya he configurado varias veces el realm en glassfish revisado las tablas campos, archivos y no logro encontrar el error como para que me genere esto:

```
Advertencia:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception 
Grave:   [LoginBean][iniciarSesion] Excepcion -> Login failed
```

Estas son las tablas que tengo en la base de datos

```
CREATE TABLE uc.sis_usuarios
(
    nickname character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    contrasena character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    estado boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    img_perfil text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT pk_usuario PRIMARY KEY (nickname)
)

CREATE TABLE uc.sis_niveles
(
    nombre character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    estado boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    CONSTRAINT pk_nivel PRIMARY KEY (nombre)
)

CREATE TABLE uc.sis_nivel_usuarios
(
    idusuario character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    idnivel character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_nivel_usuario PRIMARY KEY (idusuario, idnivel),
    CONSTRAINT fk_nivel_usuarios_nivel FOREIGN KEY (idnivel)
        REFERENCES uc.sis_niveles (nombre)
    CONSTRAINT fk_nivel_usuarios_usuario FOREIGN KEY (idusuario)
        REFERENCES uc.sis_usuarios (nickname)
)
```

**Mi configuración del Realm**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi archivo de **glassfish-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>Coordinador</role-name>
    <group-name>Coordinador</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

El archivo web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbc/Realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>Coordinador</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Zona de Administracion</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Area de perfiles de usuarios</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/perfil/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Coordinador</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme he intentado casi de todo (creando de nuevo el proyecto, creando el rem varias veces, las tablas, las bases, la encriptación SHA-256 en vez de la MD5 de la contraseña, etc) y no logro hacer que funcione, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo deberias activa el registro TRACE para la categoría "org.jboss.security".

```
 <logger category="org.jboss.security">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
 </logger>
```

Una vez hecho esto debería mostrar el motivo del error en el .log yo he hehco esto pero con el Serv de app Wildfly y no me daba en cuenta que estaba mal los querys además podrias también poner tu  `<security-domain name="jdbc/Realm" >`para verlo con más detalle. Saludos!!!

Comment: Primeramente disculpa la respuesta muy tardada. Esto me ha funcionado logre dectear el problema y no era mas que encriptaba dos veces la contraseña una con mi codigo y otra que estaba configurada en el glassfish

Comment: Estamos para ayudarnos amigo agradecería un voto!!!